# Grpc Spring Boot Starter

Tags: spring-boot, grpc-java

I am trying to integrate a grpcService to my spring boot application. In this service class i have a jpaRepository which is @Autowired. When i run the server this repository is not injected( is null when i'm trying to use it).

```java
@Service
public class MedicationPlanService extends medicationPlanGrpc.medicationPlanImplBase {

    @Autowired
    private MedicationPlanRepository medicationPlanRepository;


    @Override
    public void hello(MedicationPlan.HelloRequest request, StreamObserver<MedicationPlan.HelloResponse> responseObserver) {
        List<MedicationPlan> medicationPlans = medicationPlanRepository.findAll();


        MedicationPlan.HelloResponse.Builder response = MedicationPlan.HelloResponse.newBuilder();

        response.setResponseMessage("hello");

        responseObserver.onNext(response.build());
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class GrpcServerStartConfiguration {

    @PostConstruct
    public void startGrpcServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(9091).addService(new MedicationPlanService()).build();
        server.start();
        System.out.println("gRPC server started");
        server.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

When i try to use the medicationPlanRepository i realized that it is null.
Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Hi how did you manage to inject the MedicationPlanRepository in the grpc class? I have the same problem Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're creating MedicationPlanService with "new", it becomes a simple object, not a bean. And things such as DI don't work in this way.

Initialize these 2 classes correctly (via @ComponentScan or @Bean in @Configuration class). Then inject MedicationPlanService into GrpcServerStartConfiguration. The latter you can mark as @Configuration for better understaning btw.

Comment: I successfully injected the service but now when i call findAll() method on the medicationPlanRepository it enters an infinite loop. This repository is extending CrudRepository.

Comment: Please update your question with this information (and explain the infinite loop situation more verbose)

Comment: I uploaded some images with the updated code and the "infinite loop" problem : https://imgur.com/a/IDmIm5V

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. Apparently the gRPC server was blocking the REST server although they were on different ports. I created a separate thread on which i run the gRPC server. Thanks a lot for your answer :)